# Perl WWW-Mechanize Module

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I am using www-mechanize module to access website controls. Some html pages contains frames. I cant get the links names and i am unable to access the links in frames. Please any one suggest right solution to resolve this issue.

Working Platform: Windows, Perl

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From what I see, WWW::Mechanize does not load frames automatically; you need to do so yourself.  You can get links to the frames with:

```
@frames = $mech->find_link( 'tag' => 'frame' );
```

and then `$mech->get` each one (cloning your mech object if necessary).